# What is the correct way to say "have a shot (of a drink) in praise of your youth days"?

Tags: sentence, collocation

What is the correct, usual way in English to say "have a shot (of a drink) in praise of your youth days"?

Comment: Depending: "let's toast your youth!", etc., 'toast' being the operative verb, used in the sense of 'to drink in honour of a person or thing'.

Comment: ***Here's to** X*, ***Please raise your glasses** to X*, ***I'd like to propose a toast*** to X*,...  But we don't use the term ***youth days*** - just ***youth*** (or ***salad days*** if you're feeling poetic).

Comment: Except in formal surroundings, we don't usually applaud our youthful good behaviour, or how wisely we spent our time, with a drink — rather the opposite: "**Let's drink to our mis-spent youth!**" despite one's success in life.

Comment: @JEL Thanks. If it's an old character in a film saying this to another old character, and asks him to toast in praise of his youth after showing a photo of those days to him, would we say the same?

Comment: Go with FumbleFingers. "Here's to" or "raise your glass to". Or just "these were the days, my friend, we thought they'd never end".

Comment: @RegDwigнt Damn, now I've got an ear worm.

Comment: In the scenario you propose, I think 'toast' in the phrasing may be *more* usual than options such as are suggested in other comments. Most usual of all may be simple brevity, however: "To your youth!" That it is a proposed toast would *usually* be evident from the physical context

Answer (score -1):

“To the riotous enjoyment of X.”  [How to Give a Toast](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-give-a-toast/)

As in your example:

> have a shot (of a drink) in praise of your youth days

I would suggest:

> “To the riotous enjoyment of your youth!  Or "Let's drink with riotous enjoyment to your youth!"  (with glasses raised ... toast ... drink ... then all glasses thrown aside!)

Seriously, one does not have to throw the glass or container!"

Good article on all thing 'toast'! There many examples of toast for all occasions!  Just stand up, raise you glass and speak you mind ... carefully.

Comment: Thanks. If it's an old character in a film saying this to another old character, and asks him to toast in praise of his good days when he was young, after showing a photo of those days to him, would we say the same?

Comment: if it applies to both older characters i would say:  "I toast to the days of our youth!"